# Help with factoring $a^4(b-c)+b^4(c-a)+c^4(a-b)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

I want to factor $a^4(b-c)+b^4(c-a)+c^4(a-b)$. I found a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/918976/factoring-a4b-cb4c-ac4a-b) on the site, but still don't know how to factor it. from Macavity's answer I realized it has the factor of $(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)$. as mentioned in the answer I should find a quadratic that after multiplying on this factor getting the initial expression. I expanded these expressions:

$$a^4b-a^4c-b^4c-b^4a+c^4a-c^4b=(a^2b-a^2c-b^2a+b^2c+ac^2-bc^2)\times\underbrace{(\quad\quad\quad)}_\text{quadratic expression}$$
I don't know how to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See both polynomials as polynomials in $a$; the numerator is$$(b-c)a^4+(-b^4+c^4)a+b^4c-bc^4\tag1$$and the denominator is$$(b-c)a^2+(-b^2+c^2)a+b^2c-bc^2.\tag2$$Now, apply long polynomial division to $(1)$ and $(2)$, and you will get$$a^2+(b+c)a+b^2+bc+c^2.$$

Comment: I got this expression as denominator $(b-c)a^2+(-b^2+c^2)a+(b^2c-bc^2)$

Comment: Then you made a mistake somewhere. Since the coefficient of the term with highest degree is $b-c$ both in the numerator and in the denominator, the quotient has to be a monic polynomial.

Comment: I mean the expression you tagged as $(2)$ should be $(b-c)a^2+(-b^2+c^2)a+(b^2c-bc^2)$ I think there is a typo in your answer

Comment: You right. I have edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: I really like this answer. you wrote the polynomials in $a$ and it helps a lot in doing long division. I just finished the long division and it was much easier than what I thought :)

Comment: It doesn't look easy before you do it. I agree.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(a,b,c)$ be the polynomial to factor. Write
$f(a,b,c)= g(a,b,c)(a-b)(a-c)(b-c)$ with $g(a,b,c)=r_1a^2+r_2ab+r_3ac+r_4b^2+r_5bc+r_6c^2$. Compare coefficients to obtain
$$
g(a,b,c)=a^2 + ab + ac + b^2 + bc + c^2.
$$
One can make this more efficient by arguing that the coefficients for $ac,ab,bc$ must be equal and the ones for $a^2,b^2,c^2$ as well.

So we have the factorization
$$
f(a,b,c)=(a^2 + ab + ac + b^2 + bc + c^2)(a - b)(a - c)(b - c)
$$

Comment: My problem is I don't know how to divide it. should I use expanded version and doing long division?

Comment: I edited my answer. It is easier to compare coefficients.

Comment: Oh thank you. I will try that.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Since the polynomial is symmetric over a,b,c it is easy to note that The coefficients of $a^2,b^2,c^2$ and the coefficients of $ab, bc,ca$ will be the same. That would make the job easier.

Comment: Note that the original expression is anti-symmetric, and that the identified factor is antisymmetric (changes sign whenever two of the letters are switched). This implies that the quadratic factor is symmetric and must be of the form $s(a^2+b^2+c^2)+t(ab+bc+ca)$ and that makes comparing coefficients more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

I think the following method is better :we have  $$a^4(b-a+a-c)+b^4(c-a)+c^4(a-b)$$ $$=(a^4-c^4)(b-a)+(a-c)(a^4-b^4)$$ $$=(a-c)(b-a)(a^3+ac^2+a^2c+c^3)+(a-c)(a-b)(a^3+ab^2+a^2b+b^3)$$ $$=(a-c)(b-a)(\color{blue}{ac^2-ab^2}+\color{red}{a^2c-a^2b}+\color{green}{c^3-b^3})$$ can you end it now?

> Note we just used well known identities $a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+...b^{n-1})$